# MongoDB $max operator not working properly on updation

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB $max operator to update total of selected document if the value is higher than the old value. like below,

```
public bool UpdateTotal( string docid,long newtotal)
        {
            try
            {
                var collection= db.Collection<MyCollection>("MyCollection");
                var filter = Builders<MyCollection>.Filter.Eq("docID", docid);
                var updatedata = Builders<MyCollection>.Update.Max(x=>x.Total, newtotal);
                var upoptions = new UpdateOptions();
                var res = collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter,updatedata);
                res.Wait();
                var issuccess = res.Result.IsAcknowledged;
                Debug.WriteLine("MongoDBUpdate  " + newtotal+ " " +res.Result.ModifiedCount);
                return issuccess;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

The Query is updating the field in MongoDB. **But the problem is when it is run concurrently the update is happening more than once.** The debugger is showing modified count=1 in more than one request. why is this happening ?, how can I stop this from happening in this situation.
can someone tell help me see what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: if you send the update more than 1 time, to the database why to not update also more than 1 times? if you dont want the update to happen, you can add at filter, that the max you will add to be bigger than the existing max, in that case no update will happen for the same max, even if you send the update many times. i dont know maybe i didnt understanded the problem.

Comment: you were rigth @Takis_ it worked for me with the filter updation , thanks